# Django: Editable BINARY field which displays as HEX in Admin

Tags: django, django-models

**update** I have now figured that there *is* a reason to define `get_prep_value()` and that doing so improves Django's use of the field. I have also been able to get rid of the wrapper class. All this has, finally, enabled me to also eliminate the `__getattribute__ implementation with the data model, which was annoying. So, apart from Django calling`to_python()` super often, I'm now fine as far as I can see. **/update**

One morning, you wake up and find yourself using Django 1.4.2 along with DjangoRESTFramework 2.1.2 on Python 2.6.8. And hey, things could definitely be worse. This Django admin magic provides you with forms for your easily specified relational data model, making it a pleasure to maintain the editorial part of your database. Your business logic behind the RESTful URLs accesses both the editorial data and specific database tables for their needs, and even those are displayed in the Django admin, partially because it's easily done and nice to have, partially because some automatically generated records require a mini workflow.

But wait. You still haven't **implemented those binary fields as BINARY. They're VARCHARS**. You had put that on your ToDo list for later. And later is now.

Okay, there are those write-once-read-many-times cases with small table sizes where an optimization would not necessarily pay. But in another case, you're wasting both storage and performance due to freuquent INSERTs and DELETEs in a table which will get large.

So what would you want to have? A **clear mapping between the DB and Django, where the DB stores BINARY and Django deals with hex strings** of twice the length. Can't be that hard to achieve, can it?

You search the Web and find folks who want CHAR instead for VARCHAR, others who want BLOBs, and everybody seems to do it a bit differently. Finally, you end up at [Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) where the VARCHAR -> CHAR case is officially dealt with. So you decide to go with this information.

Starting with `__init__()`, `db_type()` and `to_python()`, you notice that `to_python()` gets rarely called and add `__metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase` only to figure that Django now calls `to_python()` even if it has done so before. The other suggestions on the page suddenly start to make more sense to you, so you're going to wrap your data in a class, such that you can protect it from repeated calls to `to_python()`. You also follow the suggestion to `Put a __str__() or __unicode__() method on the class you're wrapping up as a field` and implement `get_prep_value()`.

While the resulting code does not do what you expect, one thing you notice is that **`get_prep_value()` never gets called** so far, so you're removing it for now. What you *do* figure is that **Django consistently appears to get a `str` from the DB and a `unicode` from the admin**, which is cool, and end up with something like this (boiled down to essentials, really).

```
class MyHexWrappeer(object):
    def __init__(self, hexstr):
        self.hexstr = hexstr
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.hexstr)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.hexstr

class MyHexField(models.CharField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase
    def __init__(self, max_length, *args, **kwargs):
        assert(max_length % 2 == 0)
        self.max_length = max_length
        super(MyHexField, self).__init__(max_length=max_length, *args, **kwargs)
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'binary(%s)' % (self.max_length // 2)
    def to_python(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, MyHexWrapper): # protect object
            return data
        if isinstance(data, str): # binary string from DB side
            return MyHexWrapper(binascii.b2a_hex(data))
        if isinstance(data, unicode): # unicode hex string from admin
            return MyHexWrapper(data)
```

And... it won't work. The reason, of course, being that while you have found a reliable way to create `MyHexWrapper` objects from all sources including Django itself, the path backwards is clearly missing. From the remark above, you were thinking that Django calls `str()` or `unicode()` for admin and `get_prep_value()` in the direction of the DB. But if you add `get_prep_value()` above, it will never be called, and there you are, stuck.

That can't be, right? So you're not willing to give up easily. And suddenly you get this one nasty thought, and you're making a test, and it works. And you don't know whether you should laugh or cry.

So now you try this modification, and, believe it or not, it just works.

```
class MyHexWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, hexstr):
        self.hexstr = hexstr
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.hexstr)
    def __str__(self): # called on its way to the DB
        return binascii.a2b_hex(self.hexstr)
    def __unicode__(self): # called on its way to the admin
        return self.hexstr
```

It just works? Well, if you use such a field in code, like for a RESTful URL, then you'll have to make sure you have the right kind of string; that's a matter of discipline.

But then, it still only works most of the time. Because when you make such a field your primary key, then Django will call `quote(getattr())` and while I found a source claiming that `getattr()` "nowdays" will use `unicode()` I can't confirm. But that's not a serious obstacle once you got this far, eh?

```
class MyModel((models.Model):
    myhex = MyHexField(max_length=32,primary_key=True,editable=False)
    # other fields
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if (name == 'myhex'):
            return unicode(super(MyModel, self).__getattribute__(name))
        return super(MyModel, self).__getattribute__(name)
```

Works like a charm. However, now you lean back and look at your solution as a whole. And you can't help to figure that it's a **diversion from the documentation you referred to**, that it **uses undocumented or internal behavioural characteristics** which you did not intend to, and that it is **error-prone and shows poor usability for the developer** due to the somewhat distributed nature of what you have to implement and obey.

So **how can the objective be achieved in a cleaner way?** Is there another level with hooks and magic in Django where this mapping should be located?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When I need to create a fairly complex custom model field, I usually found that the field logic should be straight forward (mostly function calls to wrapper class), and factor out all of the condition logic (something you would have in `to_python` to the custom wrapper. That usually makes the wrapper class more complex but then it works pretty well.

Comment: @miki725 Thank you for your comment. Do you have a link to an example, or what exactly is the Django piece you refer to as _field logic_? I may be missing some overview here.

Comment: What I meant by logic is all the `if` statements in your `to_python`. Instead of having bulk of the `if` statements in the field class, I usually found that moving them to the wrapper class helped a bit. That way you have one data-structure which handles everything instead of field class returning a different data-structure each time. http://pastebin.com/LQxakcbh

Comment: Ill try to make this cleaner tonight...

Comment: @miki725 Thank you again. I have been able to get rid of the wrapper class altogether.